# C join char** with delimiter

Tags: c, char

I want to join a `char**` with a given delimiter:

```
    char *str[] = {"this", "is", "a", "test", NULL};
    char* flattened = join(str, ' ');
    printf("%s", flattened);
```

Expected contents of flattened:

```
this is a test\0
```

I came up with this implementation:

```
char* join(char** strs, char delim){
    int remaining = 128;
    char* res = (char*) malloc(remaining*sizeof(char));
    memset(res, '\0', remaining);
    char* c;
    for(c = *strs; c; c=*(++strs)){
        strncpy(res, c, remaining);
        remaining-=strlen(c)+1;
        res+=strlen(c)+1;
        *(++res)=delim;
        res++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I do not expected the joined string to exceed 128 characters, therefore I made it static and not calculated by the lengths combined.

The above solution prints an empty string.

I searched for an already tried-and-tested implementation of this but I could not find anything; if anyone can point me into the right direction or help me salvage this, that would be great.

Comment: If you have an array of strings, why don't you simply iterate over it with an index? This might simplify and maybe dodge any error.

Comment: @Román
I do not know the length of the array, because I am given it by some other library. The issue with modification I could solve by copying the original pointer.

Comment: `res+=strlen(c)+1;` Is the `+1` meant to include the delimiter? You add another space in next line: `*(++res)=delim;` This will create a gap of 2 chars between the copied string and your delimiter.

Comment: If you `malloc()` you will need to `free()` later... but you change the address obtained from `malloc()` leaking that memory.

Comment: You return a pointer that points behind the last string. Also you add the delimiter after the last string as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your `join` function greatly by:

1. Using the `calloc()` function rather than the combination of `malloc()` and `memset()`.
2. Using the index (`[]`) operator on your `strs` argument, rather than trying to increment the pointer.
3. Converting the passed single-char `delim` argument to a `nul`-terminate string.
4. Using the `strcat()` function to append each string and the separator to your `res` string.

Here is a version using those techniques:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* join(char** strs, char delim)
{
    char* res = calloc(128, sizeof(char)); // Might as well set to zero on allocation
    char* c;
    char sep[2] = { delim, '\0' }; // Convert single char into a string
    int i = 0;
    for (c = strs[i]; c; c = strs[++i]) {
        strcat(res, c);
        strcat(res, sep);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char* str[] = { "this", "is", "a", "test", NULL };
    char* flattened = join(str, ' ');
    printf("%s", flattened);
    free(flattened); // Don't forget to free the memory when you're done with it!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am quite new to C and I did not know about calloc and strcat. This is a really nice and concise solution.